# Hibernate @ManyToMany org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to deal with common error, but I cannot find the right answer.
the error is:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: newsProject.post.entity.Tag.posts, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

How to avoid use of `@Transactional`?

I am trying to do the following actions in my SpringBootTest:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class PostRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    @AfterEach
    void deleteFromDB(){
        postRepository.deleteAll();
        tagRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void deletePostWithMultipleTags(){

        Post post = new Post();

        Tag tag = new Tag(1L,"tag1", null);
        Tag tag2 = new Tag(2L,"tag2", null);
        Tag tag3 = new Tag(3L,"tag3", null);
        tagRepository.save(tag);
        tagRepository.save(tag2);
        tagRepository.save(tag3);

        post.setTitle("testTitle");

        Tag tagNew = tagRepository.findByTagName(tag.getTagName());

        post.addTag(tagNew);
        post.addTag(tagRepository.findByTagName(tag2.getTagName()));
        post.addTag(tagRepository.findByTagName(tag3.getTagName()));
        System.out.println(post);

        postRepository.save(post);

    }
}
```

The error is in this part:

```java
    public void addTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.add(tag);
        tag.getPosts().add(this);
    }
```

I am open for any additional questions that related to this problem

I do not want to use following answers:
 - Fetch.EAGER (or something related with turning down Fetch.LAZY)
 - hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=True

The code:

#### Post.java

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "post_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="post_generator", sequenceName = "seq_post", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;

    //Some code

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "post_tag",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.add(tag);
        tag.getPosts().add(this);
    }

    public void removeTag(Tag tag) {
        tags.remove(tag);
        tag.getPosts().remove(this);
    }
}
```

#### Tag.java

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "posts")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="id_generator", sequenceName = "seq_tag", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    private String tagName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags")
    List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPost(Post post) {
        posts.add(post);
        post.getTags().add(this);
    }

    public void removePost(Post post) {
        posts.remove(post);
        post.getTags().remove(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. We can avoid `@Transactional` 100%.

1. Add the following lines to the testing class:

```java
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Rollback(false)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class PostRepositoryTest {
```

as we are testing work of JPA.

2. Use in the repository interface `extends JpaRepository<..., ...>` instead of `CrudRepository<..., ...>`
3. in `tagRepository` add the line:

```java
List<Tag> findByNameIn(List<String> names);
```

[see documentation.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)

4. Now we can modify or test to this:

```java
@Test
    void deletePostWithMultipleTags(){

        Tag tag = new Tag(1L,"tag1", null);
        Tag tag2 = new Tag(2L,"tag2", null);
        Tag tag3 = new Tag(3L,"tag3", null);
        tagRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(tag, tag2, tag3));
        tagRepository.flush();

        Post post = new Post();
        post.setTitle("testTitle");

        List<Tag> tags =  tagRepository.findByNameIn(Arrays.asList(tag.getName(), tag2.getName(), tag3.getName(),));
        for (Tag tagItem : tags){
          post.addTag(tahItem);
        }

        postRepository.saveAndFlush(post);

    }
```

After all these actions you can avoid the use of `@Transactional`

Answer (score 1):

i tried your case and this is working for me. Please try :

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void test() {
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setTitle("post");

    Tag tag1 = new Tag();
    tag1.setTagName("tag1");
    tag1.getPosts().add(post);

    Tag tag2 = new Tag();
    tag2.setTagName("tag2");
    tag2.getPosts().add(post);

    post.getTags().add(tag1);
    post.getTags().add(tag2);

    postRepository.save(post1);
}
```

We benefit of cascade saving here. Don't forget to add @Transactional to your method.

Answer (score -1):

The quick fix would be either:

1. Annotate your test method with `@Transactional` (which will rollback all changes and has maybe unwanted side-effects. see [this link](https://www.marcobehler.com/2014/06/25/should-my-tests-be-transactional) for more information)
2. Annotate your test method with `@Rollback(false)`, which will span a transaction around your test and *not* rollback.